Question regarding minimum of function involving modulus and trignometric functions
The problem i am solving is as follows
Find the minimum and maximum values of the function
$$|\sin\theta - 2| + |1-\sin\theta| + |\cos\theta - 3| + |\cos\theta - 1|$$
I managed to find the minimum using the following inequalities
$$|\sin\theta - 2| + |1-\sin\theta| \geq |\sin\theta - 2 + 1 - \sin \theta| = 1$$
$$|\cos\theta - 3| + |\cos\theta - 1| \geq |\cos\theta - 3 - \cos\theta + 1| = 2$$
Hence the minimum value comes out to be three, how would i find the maximum value?, any help would be highly appreciated.

Try to simplify the absolute before working. Moreover, your `minimizer' for both inequalities may not be the same, so your lower bound may not be reachable.

For each $\theta\in\Bbb R$,

$|\sin\theta-2|=2-\sin\theta$;
$|1-\sin\theta|=1-\sin\theta$;
$|\cos\theta-3|=3-\cos\theta$;
$|\cos\theta-1|=1-\cos\theta$.

Therefore, your function is simply$$7-2\sin\theta-2\cos\theta=7-2\sqrt2\sin\left(\theta+\frac\pi4\right).$$So, the maximum and the minimum are $7+2\sqrt2$ and $7-2\sqrt2$ respectively.
